# html input field search items in database only first letter

Tags: mysql

I want to do an SQL search query where if the user inputs the name of an item it searches the database for that item but I also want to have it so if the user only inputs one letter it give all the items that match with that letter as the first letter.

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE ItemName = @search AND Location_id = @location  ";
```

Comment: `ItemName LIKE 'a%'` will find all item starting with an `a` an when settings of your database are `case insensitive` also those that start with an `A`.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the LIKE functionality. You use wildcards to add "rules" to your search query. Check this out.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp